# Implementing larger page tables

Tags: operating-system

I have studied in my operating systems class that Larger page tables can be implemented in memory management technique by using paging. When implementing this virtual memory does it really become slow memory access when it is implemented on a secondary storage device. I want to know the reason for it that how it slows down memory access? When we implement large page tables on secondary storage device.

Comment: Page table implemented on secondary storage will be slow since every time  you want to access a page, you have to access secondary storage which will be slow by several magnitudes than RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Even smaller page tables can be (and have been) implemented using paging. The architectural issue is how to get around the chicken and egg problem of page tables being in virtual memory while referring to physical memory. A number of techniques have been developed to deal with that.

Paged page tables only slows down the memory when a page table access causes a page fault. Once the page fault is serviced, subsequent references to not trigger a page fault (unless the table is paged out). Paine the page tables is not slowing down the system constantly.